# Google maps javascript API - is there a better way to know if the destination arrived than polling?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am relatively new to google maps API. I have a requirement wherein I know the destination and need to notify the user when destination arrives. User isnt expecting any navigation info. I know i can poll at some intervals to get current location and decide based on the response. But is there a better way?